# Assignment of object of one type to the other type

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

In the Code Below there are Two Classes. One Object of type two is created and then it is assigned to pointer of class one.

On Calling the out function, the out function of the class one is called.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class one
{
    public :
        void  out()
        {
            cout<<"one ";
        }
};

class two
{
    public : 
        void out()
        {
            cout<<"two ";
        }
};

int main()
{ 
    two dp[3];
    one *bp = (one *)dp;
    for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    (bp++)->out();
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
one one one
```

Output according to me should be two instead of one.
When we created the object of type two, the memory location of that object contained the address of the function of out of class two, then why on assignment, out of class one is called ?

**EDIT** -
moreover even if we change the name of function in class two, the output is not changed.

Comment: Well, you lied to the compiler. Why should you expect anything reasonable?

Comment: This is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), plain and simple.

Comment: @Amol : Because the C++ standard says that what you're doing is not legal.

Comment: @ildjarn Would be awesome you point out where C++ says so :) I am interested too :)

Comment: @ildjarn: That describes the cast, but doesn't say anything about accessing objects via pointers to the wrong type.

Comment: @Mike : It says the result of such a cast is unspecified; if there's a more relevant citation, feel free to post it. :-] EDIT: Ah, yep, that's more relevant, +1.

Comment: @nacho4d: C++11 3.10/10: "If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the
following types the behavior is undefined" (and the list of allowed types doesn't include "any old unrelated user-defined type").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not uncommon for a novice to assume that *all* C++ member functions "belong" to an object.
As you noticed, they don't.

Conceptually - the precise procedure is a compiler implementation detail - your `out` member functions are transformed into "free" functions that look like these:

```
void one_out(one* this) { cout << "one"; }
void two_out(two* this) { cout << "two"; }
```

For non-member functions, that's all that's needed.

When the compiler sees

```
  (bp++)->out();
```

it *knows* that bp is a pointer to `one` (it doesn't know that you lied), and so it calls

```
one_out(bp++);
```

because that's what compilers do.

Answer (score 1):

The output on your machine may have been "one one one" but it could just as easily have blown up, gone & gotten you ice cream, or launched the missiles.  Your code evokes Undefined Behavior.

```
class one
/*...*/

class two
/*...*/
```

Note that `one` and `two` are completely unrelated classes.  You are not deriving `two` from `one`, or vice versa.  They are entirely different types.

Because of this...

```
two dp[3];
one *bp = (one *)dp;
for (int i=0; i<3;i++)
    (bp++)->out();
```

This code evokes Undefined Behavior*.  `bp` does not point to an object of type `one`, it points to an object of type `two`.  You cannot cast pointers in this way given the above code.

(* Note:  The Undefined Behavior was when you tried to call a `one` method when the object was actually a `two`.  Casting itself does not evoke Undefined Behavior.)

This cast syntax you are using, `(one *)dp` is a C-style cast, which in this instance boils down to the equivilant of `reinterpret_cast<one*>(bp);`.  It would be best to use `reinterpret_cast` when that's what you really intend to do, if for no other reason than to write self-documenting code.

If you really are trying to get a `one*` from a `two*`, you have two options.

1. Create an inheritence hierarchy so that you can cast without evoking UB
2. Create a conversion operator so that you can construct a `one` from a `two` or vice versa.

In your case, since you're looping over an array of `one` objects and trying to execute `two` methods through those pointers, your best bet is probably #1 above.

```
class one
{
    public :
        virtual void  out()
        {
            cout<<"one ";
        }
};

class two : public one
{
    public : 
        void out()
        {
            cout<<"two ";
        }
};
```

Now your loop will work and the code will emit "two two two" instead of whatever random behavior you actually saw.

Answer (score -3):

Since your `out()` method is not declared `virtual` it is dispatched on the static type of the object not the runtime type of the object.

Also, there is no subtype relation between the two classes so it is incorrect to assign the pointers in this way.

Comment: `virtual` wouldn't be reliable either, since there's no inheritance relationship between the classes in question.

Comment: @Wug:  I rejected your edit because it completely changed the nature of Geoff Reedy's response.  You should have just posted that as an answer instead.